# Creating my own gem. Registering new Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

My idea is to create a gem, which will add a page to existing application with some service data. I've already created this application and I would like to extract it to separate gem.
It contains three files - model(not related to DB), controller and view(erb)

So my question is - how to register(or connect) my gem controller to Rails application when gem is installed or application is initialized.

Routes.rb file is to be edited manually.

Here is controller code:

```
class WebLoggersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @web_logger ||= WebLogger.instance
    @web_logger.n = params[:n]        
    log_file_name = params[:file_name] || "#{Rails.env}.log"
    @files = @web_logger.tail(log_file_name)
  end
end
```

Now WebLoggersController is undefined for application with my gem installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to achieve this is [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). Give it a try.